# Rails: respond_to PDF and HTML that has text as well as Emojis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create & download a html file in pdf format which has paragraph containing text along with Emoticons (Emojis). In output I'm able to get correct text but not the Emojis.

I have `dashboard_controller.rb` that contains the following function.

```
  def download_dashboard
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
        html = render_to_string(:layout => false, :action => "download_dashboard.html.haml")
        send_data(html, :filename => "dashboard.html", :type => 'application/pdf')
      end
    end
  end
```

Here, `download_dashboard.html.haml` has the following code

```
%p= Hello, World!
```

But the download file `dashboard.html`output I'm getting is something different like this:

[image]

The correct output should be like this:

[image]

How can I achieve the correct output?

Answer (score 1):

include char='utf-8' in `download_dashboard.html.haml`:

`%meta{:charset => "utf-8"}`